# Импорт библиотеки в проект. IDE NetBeans

Tags: java, ide

Дано:
IDE NetBeans

Библиотека [asterisk-java](https://maven.reucon.com/projects/public/asterisk-java/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/asterisk-java/building.html)

Библиотеку скачал из gita zip архивов, после чего в IDE через импорт импортировал проект.

Каким образом библиотеки\классы можно подключить к своему проекту  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос, спасибо за пинок @baihu92
Актуально для Ubuntu

```
apt-get install git
```

Устанавливает git

```
git clone https://github.com/srt/asterisk-java.git
```

Стягиваем проект

```
cd asterisk-java
```

Переходим в директорию проекта

Устанавливаем нужные либы для компиляции

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jre-lib4 Maven
```

Выполняем mvn install

После успешного выполнения заходи в папку target, берем файл asterisk-java.jar. Дальше в IDE в настройках проекта добавляет библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Авторы библиотек обычно пишут как заюзать их либу. В вашем случае не исключение.

> Then change to the created asterisk-java directory and use Maven 3 to build the project
>
> `cd asterisk-java`
>
> `mvn install`
>
> This will create the asterisk-java-$VERSION.jar in the target subdirectory as well as in your local maven repository.